# How to get already downloaded image in cache folder in android

Tags: android, caching

i am downloaded and saved images from web to my app cache folder. Now i am trying to convert particular cache folder image(PREM.jpg) into bitmap. For that i am using bellow code.

```
FileCache file = new FileCache(Context);
File f = file.getFile("PREM.jpg");
Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(f);
System.out.println("Exist status. " + f.exists());
```

But i am always getting file not exist (Exist status. false).

Actually "PREM.jpg" file name showing some thing like "-1006685176" in the cache folder.

This is my cache filder [image]

Can you please help me how to i convert that particular image into bitmap.

Thank you everyone.

Prem

Comment: are you decoding this file at a later time or immediately once it has downloaded?  I ask because you could very well pass the connection inputstream & get the BMP that way.

Comment: What is the value of f.getAbsolutePath()?